# How can I have Codeigniter method's return integer as a global variable for entire controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, methods, global-variables

I have a method in `CodeIgniter` and it returns an integer. I want this return an integer as a global variable. How can I get it?

Comment: Please post relevant code.

Comment: what you have tried so far, show code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to create a global variable inside file application/config/contants.php  as below:

```
$GLOBALS['your_variable'] = 'default_value';
```

And in your controller function, you can update its value like:

```
$GLOBALS['your_variable'] = 'new_value';
```

After updating, you can use `$GLOBALS['your_variable']` to get updated value. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can store that value in session or cookie then you can access that value in the entire project globally.

Comment: Can we use that in a custom library?

Comment: yes you can.

example code 

if you autoload the session library in config/autoload.php,

$CI =& get_instance();
if( $CI->session->userdata('username') ){
    redirect(base_url().'admin/login/');
}

 if not, you'll also need to add  $CI->load->library("session"); after $CI instantiation.